# Perl ExtUtils::MakeMaker, how to install an external config (static config for project)?

Tags: perl

I writing distribution package of my perl-program and I need to 'make install' command copy file e.g. conf/my.conf to /usr/local/etc/my.conf. 
Which parameter should I use in WriteMakefile?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found not pretty, but useful solution:

```
sub MY::postamble {
    return qq{
install :: conf/my.conf
\tcp conf/my.conf /usr/local/etc/my.conf
};
```

This is a simple add-on to Makefile to run the command when 'make install' running. In real life it's looks bit more difficult, but... =)

If there are any pretty idea, please welcome!

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't exit :) (is on the old TODO)

use `File::ShareDir::Install`/`File::UserConfig`

or try your luck with `Module::Build::SysPath`

Comment: I really don't understand how can I copy my files to specifically directory using File::ShareDir::Install, is there any simple exaple?